# Basic KML with Google Map API not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I tried my first Google Map API with KML and it bombed on me. Just seem to be a very basic problem but just can't get it to work.

Here is the script tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"> </script>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
 var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: map_center
  };
  var kml_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), mapOptions); 
  var kml_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          preserveViewport: true,
         url: 'http://someurl/mykml.kml' //Of course, I am using a valid URL here for "someurl" 
   }); 
  kml_layer.setMap(kml_map);
});
```

And here is the KML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
 <name>My placemark!</name>
 <description>Some description of my placemark.</description>
 <Point>
 <coordinates>-34.397, 150.644</coordinates>
 </Point>
 </Placemark>
 </kml>
```

I do not see the placemark.  I see the GoogleMap of the whole planet with no zoom... nothing else. Where am I going wrong? No errors in the console either.

Comment: What happens if you display the KML on Google Maps?

Comment: Is your KML being served with the correct [MIME type](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server)?

Comment: validator said `coordinates tuple is not within the valid latitude range of +/-90 [1].`

Comment: KML coordinates are longitude,latitude; no spaces allowed.

Comment: @Anto Jurković, I changed the range to numbers within what you suggested though I do not think that is the problem. It did not resolve it. Thanks any way for the suggestion.

Comment: @geocodezip Upvoted all your suggestions. Very enlightening. The one that worked partially was "KML coordinates are longitude,latitude; no spaces allowed." However, the display is with max zoom. I went back on Google... and searched to see your suggestion in another post. But  kml_layer.getStatus() returns "undefined." kml_layer.getMap() and .getUrl() do return some values. MIME types: I added handlers in my .htaccess file for the folder, just in case. In Google Earth, it shows zoom factor midway, as expected. THANKS A LOT! Any help with this zoom issue would be appreciated.

Comment: @geocodezip If you put your comment of "no spaces allowed" as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KML coordinates are longitude,latitude](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates); no spaces allowed.